# android passing activity.this to method

Tags: java, android, class, oop, android-activity

I have an app with lots of activities and almost on each I am creating a table filling with sqlite data like this:

```
  if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            TextView data;
            TableRow row;
            int cnt = 0 ;

            do {
                row = new TableRow(myActivity.this);
                row.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
                if (cnt++ % 2 == 0)
                    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                for (int x = 0; x < cursor.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                    //   arReport[i] += cursor.getString(x);
                    data = new TextView(myActivity.this);
                    if (x == 0) {
                        data.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                        data.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    }
                    data.setText(cursor.getString(x));
                    row.addView(data);

                }
                theView.addView(row);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            theView.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
            theView.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        }
```

So I wanted to create a separate class with static method drawTable() which will create this table in each activity on call. However I need to pass activity name as a parameter to that method so I can do  row = new TableRow(myActivity.this).. I was trying to replace myActivity.this with getActivity() or just this -- it didnt work. Please suggest what should I use to do that...

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the separate class and pass your activity's context in the constructor

```
public class DbHadler {

Context context;

public DbHandler(Context context) {

    this.context= context;

}

public void drawTable(Activity activity) {

    //relevent code

    Table row;
    row = new Table(activity);

}
```

And then use this class in your activity like this

```
DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

or if fragment then,

```
DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getContext());
```

And then its method in your activity like this.

```
db.drawTable(this);
```

or if fragment then,

```
db.drawTable(getActivity());
```